# Spring Mail Integration - How do i convert org.springframework.messaging.Message to javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Im am creating a service that needs to listen & handle any new emails that are received in a mail account.

**Problem:** I am unable to convert the message that I receive in the `handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message)` method into any form of MimeMessage type that I can work with to get the to/cc addresses an/or any file attached.

My MailConfiguration Class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.dsl.Mail;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.support.DefaultMailHeaderMapper;
import org.springframework.integration.mapping.HeaderMapper;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Configuration
public class MailConfiguration {

     @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow imapMailFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imaps://username:pass123@imap.gmail.com:" + 993 + "/INBOX")
                                .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true"))
                                .headerMapper(mailHeaderMapper()),
                        e -> e.autoStartup(true).poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .handle(new MailHandler())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public HeaderMapper<MimeMessage> mailHeaderMapper() {
        return new DefaultMailHeaderMapper();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }
}
```

My MailHandler Class:

```
import org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Component
public class MailHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("RECEIVED NEW MAIL");

        //Doesnt Work
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) message.getPayload();

        //Doesnt Work
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) message;

    }
}
```

If it's possible to convert the message to a custom domain model that would also work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access to all the email content including attachments, you need to configure an `autoCloseFolder(false)` and should not have that `.headerMapper(mailHeaderMapper())`.

See Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RC1/reference/html/mail.html#mail-mapping

> When message mapping is enabled, the payload depends on the mail message and its implementation. Email contents are usually rendered by a `DataHandler` within the `MimeMessage`.

And also here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RC1/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound

> Keeping the folder open is useful in cases where communication with the server is needed during parsing multipart content of the email with attachments.

This way a `message.getPayload()` in your handler indeed can be cast to the `MimeMessage`.

Comment: How to print message to console without `.headermapper(mailHeaderMapper)` ? Any idea?